# Need help in Pattern matching in java

Tags: java, regex

I have input string as

```
String str = "IN Param - {Parameter|String}{Parameter|String}  Out Param - {Parameter   Label|String}{Parameter Label2|String}";
```

I should able to get

> {Parameter|String}{Parameter|String}

from In Param and

> {Parameter   Label|String}{Parameter Label2|String}

from Out Param.

And again in In Param, I should be able to get Parameter and string. How is it possible in regular expression matching Java?

Comment: You want to move back to `In Param` after matching `Out Param`? Can you show some code, you might have tried?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible through groups

So the regex is:

```
"\\{(.*?)\\|(.*?)\\}"
```

**Group1** captures Parameter

**Group2** captures String

In this regex `{(.*?)|` says match 0 to n characters that begins with `{` and ends with `|` and store the result in group1 excluding `{` and `|`..This happens similarly with `|(.*?)}` but it stores the result in group2..

try it [here](http://fiddle.re/80dp)

Comment: Bonus point for the link to regexplanet.com. That will come in handy!

Comment: What is the meaning of \\, (.*?) in regex

Comment: @user900721 `.`(dot) means match any character. `.*` means match 0 to many characters.`.*?` is similar to `.*` but it restricts to first match..`{` has special meaning in regex..so we need to escape it with `\\`..regex is **very simple**..u will find many tutorials for it..google it!

Comment: supposing if i want to exclude { and | but want those characters between them what would i have to do?

Comment: @Morpheus you need to use Groups..As i said the above regex would capture the in between strings in Group 1 and 2..So,if `m` is a `Matcher` object,you can access the in between strings with `m.Group(1)` and `m.Group(1)`

Comment: The object i am looking to pattern looks like SampleObj [field1=20, field2="Some value"] i need to extract 20 and Some value from this,  so i used this \\=(.*?), which is giving me 20 but unable to get the second one because that ends with ] any pointers?

Comment: @Morpheus the regex should be `\\[field1\\=([^,]*),\\s*field2\\=\\"([^\\"]*)\\"\\]`..Group1 and 2 captures the required data

Comment: Thanks so much, i tried this on the regex site this doesn't seem to match the pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^|]+)\\|([^}]+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    String label = m.group(1);
    String value = m.group(2);
    // do what you need with them
}
```